# Showing full dashboard on Home Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, dashboard, home-page-component, home-page-layout

I am using the following Visualforce page to display my full dashboard on my home page vs just the first 3 rows:

```
<apex:page >
  <src="/01Z14000000kQBw?isdtp=nv" scrolling="true" height="1000px" width="100%"/> 
</apex:page>
```

however when I load up my home page, it's just blank.  I am curious as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will not work.Try building dashboard with analytics:reportchart and embed this page in visuaforce homecomponent

```
 <apex:page> 
 <apex:panelGrid columns="3">
   <apex:panelGroup id="theGroup1">
   <apex:outputText>Report 1</apex:outputText>
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O55000000OZVL" />
   </apex:panelGroup>
   <apex:panelGroup id="theGroup2">
   <apex:outputText>Report 2</apex:outputText>
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O55000000OZVM" />
   </apex:panelGroup>
   <apex:panelGroup id="theGroup3">
   <apex:outputText>Report 3</apex:outputText>
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O55000000OZVO" />
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:panelGroup id="theGroup4">
   <apex:outputText>Report 4</apex:outputText>
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O55000000OZVS" />
   </apex:panelGroup>
   <apex:panelGroup id="theGroup5">
   <apex:outputText>Report 5</apex:outputText>
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O55000000OZVN" />
   </apex:panelGroup>
   <apex:panelGroup id="theGroup6">
   <apex:outputText>Report 6</apex:outputText>
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O55000000OZVI" />
    </apex:panelGroup>
</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This works well, the only issue is, is there a way to get the chart's name to display?

Comment: @B.Wayne updated code